# Polylang not translating Metabox fields

Tags: metabox, plugin-polylang

I'm using Polylang to make my website multilingual. but when I edit a custom metabox's field in a post, the same field in the post's other language also changes to that. So that it seems that the metaboxes are only in one language!

Comment: @toscho Of course this question is not off-topic unless you have never heard of Polylang!

Comment: @pooria Please read our [on-topic page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). It states very clearly that third-party plugin support is not on-topic here. Don't shoot the messenger. :)

Comment: @toscho read this:https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic WordPress Stack Exchange is for WordPress developers and administrators to ask questions about:

theme and plugin development
development and management best practices
server configuration for WordPress

Comment: @toscho This place is a place to help wordpress developers. Wordpress real developers have often to fight against plugins. If you want to fully honor the mission of a site like this, you must let people ask about plugins too, as long as custom code is implied. This question should be reopened because there will be people out there coming here willing to find a solution to this very problem, and this thread will be useful for them. They will be coders, they will be wordpress users. So what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off custom fields syncronisation on polylang.

I would also then add specific code to tell polylang to copy (not sync) the metas upon translation creation (so when you click '+' it will also copy the metas, but changing the metas after this, won't sync with other translations):

```
add_filter('pll_copy_post_metas', 'copy_post_metas', 10, 2);
function copy_post_metas($metas, $sync){
  if(!is_admin()) return false;
  if($sync) return $metas;
  global $current_screen;

  if($current_screen->post_type == 'wine'){ // sustitute 'wine' with your post type
    $keys = array_keys(get_fields($_GET['from_post'])); // an example from ACF
    return array_merge($metas, $keys);
  }

  return $metas;
}
```

Reference: https://polylang.pro/doc/filter-reference/